# Regex that matches up string or end of line

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a javascript regex that matches strings that start with # and end on either \n# or end of line (which ever comes first).

Samples - https://regex101.com/r/rpjPkl/4

For the following samples:

Sample 1: `#always: test\n#asdf`

Results: `#always: test` with groups `always` and `test`

Sample 2: `#always: test\n#range: [0, 255]`

Results: `#always: test` with groups `always` and `test`

and `#range: [0, 255]` with groups `range` and `[0, 255]`

I've tried (for hours...) various versions of the following:

```
#([a-z]+):(.+)((\\n#)|$)
#([a-z]+):((^\\n#)|$)+
```

---

Update 1:

The group results should separate out `\n` if its found. If its not possible to get above groups, at min, I need the following group results

Sample 1 expecting groups: `#always: test`

Sample 2 expecting groups: `#always: test` and `#range: [0, 255]`

Note that `\n` can exist as a group but can't included in the above groups.

---

Update 2

I'm providing a more exhaustive sample that should cover (hopefully) all scenarios.

Live sample link: https://regex101.com/r/rpjPkl/4 The answer must test against the Test String found in this link (same as below Sample 3).

Sample 3:

```
#always: line1\nline#2\n#range: [0, 255]\n#obj: { prop: '#a1',
prop2: 2 }\n#more: "where #2"
```

Expected matches / groups

Match 1: `#always: line1\nline#2`
Group 1: `always`
Group 2: `line1\nline#2`

Match 2: `#range: [0, 255]`
Group 1: `range`
Group 2: `[0, 255]`

Match 3:

```
#obj: { prop: '#a1',
            prop2: 2 }
```

Group 1: `obj`
Group 2:

```
{ prop: '#a1',
            prop2: 2 }
```

Match 4: `#more: "where #2"`
Group 1: `more`
Group 2: `"where #2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to capture repeating patterns, you could perform an initial split on each sample by newline first, to make the matching easier.

```js
const samples = [
  '#always: test\n#asdf',
  '#always: test\n#range: [0, 255]'
]

function foo(sample)
{
  // split first, and then iterate over each sentence
  return sample.split('\n').map(sentence => {
    // this expression is now very basic
    return sentence.match(/^#([a-z]+):\s*(.+)/)
    // empty matches yield null and will get filtered later
  }).filter(match => match !== null)
}

samples.forEach(sample => {
  console.log(foo(sample));
})
```

Comment: Would this be more efficient than a single regex?

Comment: @SILENT depends on what that performance would buy you; I'm going for simplicity and ease to extend here ... besides, regular expressions, in their essence, are already relatively slow

Comment: @SILENT does this answer your question adequately?

Comment: I didn't use your regex but used your advice. Was simpler to implement.